Ubuntu can't wake up after sleeping. Ubuntu 24.04 and gtx4060
Ubuntu can't wake up after sleeping and closing the lid. It is black screen. I must restart my computer to use it. I tried almost every method from internet, such as ctrl+alt+f1 ~f7, laptop model setting,
xscreensaver, forbiding nouveau. But all failed.
Some information:

Ubuntu 24.04
nvidiagtx 4060
intel core
asus computer
driver version nvidia 535 (tested).

I tried changing the driver to another (535 open), but it doesn't work. In addition, the new driver made my computer worse, more sluggish.

Please edit the question and add exactly what you have tried and the results.

Please try this
create file
/etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-power-management.conf 

with following content
options nvidia NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations=1 NVreg_TemporaryFilePath=${TMP_PATH}

This option preserves video memory contents.
I found this in Arch Wike (sorry was in german so no link from me)

thank your for your answer.I tried it  just now,but it didn't work for me .

journalctl -b -1 | grep -i error  found some discussion https://gist.github.com/bmcbm/375f14eaa17f88756b4bdbbebbcfd029

thank you very much.by your link,I tried many methods. at the last method,(remove some  file )sloved my problem forever.Contraguration~~~ thank you again.wish you have a good day.

One liner (I don't see how to make it a movable box.  It should all be one line):
echo "options nvidia NVreg_PreserveVideoMemoryAllocations=1 NVreg_TemporaryFilePath=/var/tmp" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/nvidia-power-management.conf
Cannot add a comment, but nobody was mostly correct, you need a valid path for the TemporaryFilePath, for most that would be /var/tmp (if you are using btrfs and have a nocow tmp. you probably want to use that).
